# Js switch between two options without "if"

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if theres a build-in command in js that allow me to switch two states of an element back and forth.

I have for an example this code:

```
mydiv.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="this.innerHTML=\'Second_possible_value\';">Default value</a>';
```

What i need is to switch between "Default_value" and "Second_possible_value" in place. I don't want to write whole if{}-else{}

```
onclick="this.innerHTML.MagicalSwitch('Second_possible_value'||'Default_value');"
```

Is there something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this for 2 http://jsfiddle.net/or9d4aLk/

```
onclick="this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML == 'Default_value' ? 'Second_possible_value' : 'Default_value';"
```

or this for 3 http://jsfiddle.net/or9d4aLk/1/

```
onclick="this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML == 'Default_value' ? 'Second_possible_value' : this.innerHTML != 'Third_possible_value' ? 'Third_possible_value' : 'Default_value';"
```

Comment: Haha i swear to god i didnt see your answer and just typed this from my phone. But again, if you program with JS this is something you do everyday. Anyway, just deleted my answer.. Too late

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes I feel you! You know what they say, great minds think alike.

Comment: I look at the conditional operator syntax but never thought that `this.innerHTML` can be used as a variable in it :) You guys are great. And now a riddle - can there be third possible value aded, used and cycle switched ??

Comment: @Bri.H. There sure can be! Ill add it to the answer.

Comment: @AndrewM New emoji :D
`= == ? : != ? :`

Answer (score 0):

You could have two methods. When one method finished it switches the onclick event to the other method.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The nice way to do this is not to use event attributes. Use the proper system (`addEventListener`) instead. Then you can do something like this:

var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');

```js
(function() { // create a closure for our counting variable
  var i = 0, // to count how many times this has been run
    link = document.createElement('a');

  link.href = '#';
  mydiv.appendChild(link); // add the a element to the div
  link.innerHTML = 'Default_value';

  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (i++ % 2) { // i.e. on even operations
                   // n.b we increment i
      link.innerHTML = 'Default_value';
    } else { // i.e. on odd-numbered operations
      link.innerHTML = 'Second_possible_value';
    }
  }, false);
}());
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

It is, of course, a lot more verbose than the inline solution, but it will have better performance and be easier to maintain. It is also a lot more flexible, since I imagine your application has rather more functionality than just changing the words in a link.

Comment: Yes, I thought about separate function but since already `mydiv` was dynamicaly created by another function and another conditions I didn't want to complex my code.

Comment: @Bri.H. More complex doesn't always mean worse. You try debugging dynamically created inline attributes in two years' time! This would, of course, seem less complex if you didn't have to dynamically generate the `a` element.